# How to inherit the parent class in child class in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var f_obj = {
    fname: 's',
    setfname: function (x) {
        this.fname = x;
    };
}
var l_obj = {
    lname: 'o',
    setlname: function (x) {
        this.lname = x;
    };
}
```

How to inherit the f_obj in l_obj by that i can access parent method using child object.

```
lobject = new l_obj();
```

Is the below block of sentence is possible in  java script

```
lobject.setfname("stack");
lobject.setlname("overflow");
```

Comment: you need to read about javscript constructor functions and prototypal inehritance

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can use `lobject = l_obj()`, just without the `new`. That's in case you want to change the parent method too.

Comment: @NadavS.—you can't call an object, you can only call functions (well, strictly, you can only call callable objects but they are called functions or methods).

Comment: There must be a thousand articles on implementing classic OO inheritance in javascript (e.g. [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html), but in the end you'll find that complex inheritance schemes are unnecessary (as Douglas Crockford says in the closing paragraph of the linked article).